# Buttons to change columns in visual

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have been trying to solve a problem where I have a visual (`table/matrix`) where I would like different columns (`measures`) to be displayed depending on the user clicking buttons (or any other viable solution).

There are **4 combinations** the user can select **2 categories** from:

|  | Non-cat | Cat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| No IBNR | Non-cat, No IBNR | Cat, No IBNR |
| IBNR | Non-cat, IBNR | Cat, IBNR |

So for any of the combinations above, a table should be displayed below with specific measures as columns.

- I’ve  tried to use **bookmarks** and **buttons** but this got very messy as I would need many buttons to satisfy the 4 possibilities.
- Also, with my approach: I think I would need `4` copies of the table pasted on top of each other and then I need to hide them.

Is there a cleaner way of solving this ?